# Let $f$ be a map from the real projective plane to the torus. Show that $f$ must be homotopic to a constant map.

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

Let $f$ be a map from the real projective plane to the torus. Show that $f$ must be homotopic to a constant map. This is a qual problem. Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the universal cover of the torus is contractible, it's enough to show that such a map must lift to the universal cover.  When does that happen?

Comment: (I can provide more of a hint later on, if you'd like)